# How do you get html attributes in a javascript function with a variable element?

Tags: javascript, html, xslt

When a user clicks on an  element in my HTML, I want a new tab to appear in their browser and the attributes of the element they clicked on to be printed in that window.

This is a typical  element in the HTML:

```
<a id="d0e110" onclick="GetWordFile(this.id)" attr1="attr1_value" attr2="attr2_value" attr3="attr3_value">ElementContent</a>
```

There are many such elements. The UID is generated for each one during the XLST transformation ('id="{generate-id()}"').

This is my current javascript function:

```
            <script>
                function GetWordFile(id) {
                var opened = window.open("");
                opened.document.write();
                }
            </script>
```

If the last line of the function is "opened.document.write(id);", and an  element is clicked, then the new window displays the correct UID for the clicked  element. So the connection has been successfully established.

However, I cannot make any other attributes of the  element appear in the new window. The following function, for example, produces a blank new window:

```
            <script>
                function GetWordFile(id) {
                var opened = window.open("");
                opened.document.write(attr1);
                }
            </script>
```

So does trying to get the attribute as a variable:

```
            <script>
                function GetWordFile(id) {
                var opened = window.open("");
                var a1 = getAttribute("attr1");
                opened.document.write(a1);
                }
            </script>
```

I've also tried substituting inner HTML for document.write.

Can anyone identify what I am doing wrong and what my next steps should be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `getAttribute()` as a method of the element, which you can get using `document.getElementById()`.

```
function GetWordFile(id) {
    var el = document.getElementById(id);
    var attr1 = el.getAttribute('attr1');
    var opened = window.open("");
    opened.document.write(attr1);
}
```

Instead of passing `this.id` as the function argument, you might consider just passing `this`. Why force the function to search for the element when you can just provide it directly? Then the function would be like:

```
function GetWordFile(el) {
    var attr1 = el.getAttribute('attr1');
    var opened = window.open("");
    opened.document.write(attr1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Barmar, that's really helpful, especially as I get to pass the entire element to the function. I didn't mention this in the question (trying to deal with one thing at a time) but I ideally wanted to print the <a> element's innerHTML too and this means I can do that.

However, it only worked when I passed `this.id`, not `this`. I am not sure why - from what I have seen of `this` elsewhere, you should be right...

Comment: Did you remove the call to `getElementById()` when you made this change? See my updated answer.

Comment: I didn't remove `getElementById()`, which does indeed explain why I still needed the id! In your second version of the function, where are you defining variable el? Or does el come to mean the clicked element because through the use of "this"? i.e.,

Element:
`<a onclick="getWordFile(this)">....</a>`

Function: `var GetWordFile(el) { ... }`

Comment: Made a typo, that should be `function GetWordFile`. `el` is the function parameter, so it's defined by the argument in the function call. In `GetWordFile(this)`, `this` is the anchor that was clicked on, and it becomes `el` inside the function.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass `this.attributes` to the function, `.filter()` attributes that are not `onclick`, `.map()` the `.value` of the attributes to an array

```html
<script>
  function GetWordFile(attrs) {
    attrs = [...attrs].filter(attr => {
      return attr.name !== "onclick"
    }).map(attr => attr.value);
    
    console.log(attrs);
  }
</script>

<a id="d0e110" onclick="GetWordFile(this.attributes)" attr1="attr1_value" attr2="attr2_value" attr3="attr3_value">ElementContent</a>
```

Comment: Thanks! That works perfectly well, within the terms of my question. I prefer @Barmar's solution, as it seems to offer more flexibility by letting me make each attribute a variable and then arrange these in the output, whereas this produces an array that would require further work to split up. However, I never said this was a requirement so you weren't to know. 

One further question, if I may: I wasn't able to filter out more than one attribute at a time using your function. Is this possible and, if so, how?

Comment: @EysteinThanisch You can use OR operator to filter multiple values `return attr.name !== "onclick" || attr.name !== "attr1" || ..`

Answer (score 0):

When you are loading a new window you are creating a new document that does not necessarily know that any other documents exist. In order for the document to know that any other documents exist you must pass in the desired information as a parameter so as mentioned above.

```
onclick="someFunction(this)" // which passes in the current scope 
// you could then define someFunction like so to get the desired
// result
function someFunction ( htmlObject ) {
attributeList = htmlObject.attributes;
attributeArray = [...attributeList];//now can perform arrayfunctions
let a = "";
for (value in attributeArray) {
a += attributeArray[value].value + " "; // creates a string of 
attributes
}
let s = window.open("");
s.document.write(a)}
```

Note you probably want to do some array filtering because it will return all attributes but the general principle works.

Comment: Thank you for the insights! Unfortunately, I am a beginner and this solution is too complicated for me to grasp right now (and another respondant has supplied a solution I can work with). However, I'll return to it periodically and hopefully understand one day...